# Issue with pushing a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I assigned a button to push a segue to another view controller but when I execute this part of the code I get the following:

```
2014-02-20 10:44:29.357 nar[20244:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0076eca5 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x0075f07e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    4   UIKit                               0x0075f0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ce874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x0022c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x0022c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x003240c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00324484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x00323733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x0059ec7f _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    12  UIKit                               0x0026919a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    13  UIKit                               0x0026a0ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    14  UIKit                               0x0023de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    15  UIKit                               0x0022818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c283f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016c21cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016df29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x036de9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x036de809 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  w1nnar                              0x00002f2d main + 141
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7770d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And I get taken to my main file `main.m` and it highlights the following:

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Not sure what the issue is?

Suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: Show all the error message (the line before of after).

Comment: What's the message after "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" ?

Comment: @Lame Okay just found it, placed it in question.

Comment: have you tried adding an exception breakpoint?

Comment: No I don't think so...

Comment: adding one might throw some light. you can add one by going to Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create exception breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to push from a `UIViewController` not being embed in a `UINavigationController`.

What you need to do is go to your storyboard, select the `UIViewController` you're trying to push from, go to the `Editor` menu, select `Embed in`, and `Navigation Controller`. Then you can push other `UIViewControllers` on it.

For information on navigation in iOS apps, read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need a `UINavigationController` to embed your current view. Since Segues use navigation controllers to push other view controllers on top of it.

If you're using a storyboard, add a UINavigationController and embed your view in it.

Comment: So in my current view I have to add a navigation object?

Comment: the simplest way is to use the storyboard. just throw in a navigation and do ctrl+drag from navigation controller to your view controller and select "root view controller".

Comment: @P.Sami : you mean ctrl-drag

Comment: How can I edit the actual navigation to change the height of it and style, etc...?

Comment: @P.Sami ;) and David, read the doc I linked, you need to learn more about navigation, this is not related to your initial question

Comment: I know sometimes I like to get quick easy awnsers :)

Comment: your embedded view controller gets its style, etc from navigation controller (of course if you make it inferred in storyboard). You can also set those in viewDidLoad of your view controller manually.

Comment: Oh awesome, that is what I thought.

Comment: @P.Sami quick question for you, I am manually setting my background using a hex converter (method) on the `ViewController.m` on `viewDidLoad` but why is it that for my other view controllers that background color does not stay?

Comment: @DavidBiga, because that's not a property that gets inferred. View controllers don't infer everything from their predecessor.